# Access denied when trying to move a video file to another folder (Java, Windows)

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to run a code that can move a video file from one folder to another in Windows but I got an error that says access is denied.

The error occurred when I was:

i) Moving a file from C drive folder to a D drive folder

ii) Moving a file from a D drive folder to a C drive folder

Both showed the error access denied for the folder that I was trying to move the video file into. I don't think it's safe to show the file path here so I am not sharing the error. I am just a newbie in the tech and programming world though, don't know if that's true.

How do I fix this and why does this happen? The code I ran is available below.

```
public class TryUploadFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int BUFFERSIZE = 4 * 1024;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.print("Enter source file path: ");
    String sourceFilePath = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter output file path: ");
    String outputFilePath = s.nextLine();

    try (
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(sourceFilePath));
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFilePath));) {

      byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];

      while (fin.available() != 0) {
        fin.read(buffer);
        fout.write(buffer);
      }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Something went wrong! Reason: " + e.getMessage());
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Be aware that Windows will give you an access-denied error if you attempt to open a folder as if it were a file.  Are you perhaps entering a folder name for the output file path (e.g. by copying from `C:\SomeFolder\MyVideo.mov` to `D:\SomeOtherFolder`)?  Also, if you don't want to show file paths (for example, because they might contain confidential information), could you perhaps create folders `C:\tmp` and `D:\tmp` (or similar) and try copying the file between those folders?

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggestion

Use the new java [files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) copy method for your task for example

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("D","My Folder","My Video.mp3"),Paths.get("C","My Folder","My Video.mp3"), StandardCopyOptions.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

2. Possible Solution

Your C drive always asks you for administrator privileges to copy anything into it. Either take ownership of the directory you are copying into read [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10?amp) thread or maybe create an jar file from your app and run that as administrator

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking these:

1. The folder-paths you are providing. Sometimes, relative/absolute paths are not correct, resulting in this error.
2. "Write" permissions of destination folders